# Is it possible that NSNotificationCenter doesn't work on certain devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsnotificationcenter

Am using NSNotificationCenter in my iPhone App to post a notification

```
 // I add an observer in didFinishLanchingWithOptions() in the AppDelegate
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(getData:) name:kNotif_GetData object:nil];
....
....
// then in another method, I post the notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotif_GetData object:nil];
....
```

One user says that this functionality (which is executed by getData()) is not working. so that might mean that the notification hasn't gotten fired. Any idea why this might happen? When I test it with different devices, it works perfect. The user uses iPhone5 and iOS7. Is there any more setting or any explicit user setting which is needed or which could turn this on/off?

Comment: There are all sorts of possible reasons, but "NSNotificationCenter doesn't work" wouldn't be a very likely one.

Comment: One thing you should do is get the EXACT configuration of the failing device -- language setting, locale setting, timezone setting, 12/24 switch setting, etc.  Then reproduce on your device, as close as you can.

Comment: Its possible that you could be doing something *with* NSNotificationCenter that will work on one device and not another. Is the app published? Some problems will only show up in Release configuration (AppStore, Test Flight) while testing locally in Debug mode can mask it.

Answer (score 0):

No, notification centre is reliable.

"Not working" is not enough information to diagnose the problem.  Get more information from the user or add more logging so that you know what is actually going on.